# Prevent kill from outputting message

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that involves creating a background process and then killing it at some point. A stripped-down version of the strip is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 100 &
# do something
kill $!
sleep 0
```

When I run this script, it produces some (undesired) output

```
> ./script.sh         
./script.sh: line 5: 99515 Terminated: 15          sleep 100
```

This output happens even if I pipe the kill line's stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`. But for some reason it doesn't happen when I omit the last line. Why is the output being generated and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You could send a [*SIGINT*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) (or a *SIGQUIT*) (instead of a *SIGTERM*); change

```
kill $!
```

to

```
kill -n 2 $!
```

**or**

```
kill -n 3 $!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `trap`:

```bash
sleep 100 &
sleep_pid=$!

# Ignore SIGTERM
trap "" TERM

kill -TERM $sleep_pid
sleep 0
```

See `man 1p trap`:

> If `action` is null (`""`), the shell shall ignore each specified
>   condition if it arises.